# How to assign random values to props in react?

Tags: reactjs

```
 <MyComponent rotate={-5} />
 <MyComponent rotate={3} />
 <MyComponent rotate={0} />
```

Can I assign random values to same props? I have tried

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 
}

<MyComponent rotate={getRandomInt(-5, 5)}/>
```

However this props will change when page gets re-renders. I'd like to keep the props value assign at the beginning and keep it unchanged.

Or there other ways of assign random values inside MyComponent instead of pass value from outside?

Comment: What is your use case? If it's all about assigning random values, set them in `DidMount` that will give you a random at the beginning and keep it unchanged

Comment: I new to react and only familiar with functional component. The use case is something like trying draw 3 circles with random sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a random value in `useEffect` and assign it to the child component like the following if you need all the components to have the same random value

Also, you can move the generation of `random` in the `useEffect` method to the child component and get it from the state instead of props if you need each component to have a different random value "attached the code in the SandBox in the file `MyComponentFromState`

[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-einstein-dre0u?file=/src/MyComponent.jsx)

```
// MyComponent .jsx
const MyComponent = ({ random }) => {
  return <div>{random}</div>;
};

export default MyComponent;


// App.jsx
export default function App() {
  const [random, setRandom] = useState(Math.random() * 10);
  useEffect(() => {
    setRandom(Math.random() * 10);
    return () => {};
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        <MyComponent random={random} />
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried you case in sandbox link. If there are three <h1> tags with <MyComponent> they are all showing the same number. I hope to get three different values.

Comment: Yup, that is correct if the random comes from `props` take a look at the component `MyComponentFromState` I have added three components each of them have a different random number